# Compare with diff and format the output

Tags: git, shell

I take in two files with diff, is there a way I can format the output so it could say, File Name: Ascii was changed at Block Size: 1000? Instead of the regular output that just dumps all changes to a file.

```
 File A:
    File Type: regular file
    File Path: ./Secrets/711wasaparttimejob/Ascii
    File Name: Ascii
    Access Mode: -rw-r--r--
    Owner ID: 1000
    Group ID: 1000
    Block Size: 2311
    Last Modified: 2016-05-13 13:38:52.904210046 +0000
    Status Change: 2016-05-13 13:38:52.904210046 +0000
    Last Access: 2016-05-15 10:38:58.015821340 +0000
    MD5: 317ddabf4a1bd79c2ac491dba6634cb0 ./Secrets/711wasaparttimejob/Ascii


    File B:
    File Type: regular file
    File Path: ./Secrets/711wasaparttimejob/Ascii
    File Name: Ascii
    Access Mode: -rw-r--r--
    Owner ID: 1000
    Group ID: 1000
    Block Size: 1000
    Last Modified: 2016-05-13 13:38:52.904210046 +0000
    Status Change: 2016-05-13 13:38:52.904210046 +0000
    Last Access: 2016-05-15 10:38:58.015821340 +0000
    MD5: 317ddabf4a1bd79c2ac491dba6634cb0 ./Secrets/711wasaparttimejob/Ascii
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect the output from the diff command and then use **grep -E** to use regular expressions to search for what you want outputted.

For example I pasted your text into a file. And then used:

```
cat second.txt | grep -E "File Name|Block Size"
```

**Which prints out:**

```
File Name: Ascii
Block Size: 2311
File Name: Ascii
Block Size: 1000
```

cat just outputs all contents of a file. In your case *cat second.txt* will be replaced by your diff command.

```
git diff ... | grep -E "File Name|Block Size"
```